# java.lang.verifyerror in android

Tags: android

I have one android project.I have one class file of about 6000 lines when i tried to add more code it shows the java.lang.verifyerror
please help me out

Comment: If your class file is about 6000 lines I have bad news for you...

Comment: You should think about refactoring. An activity with 6000+ lines of code screams for refactoring...

Comment: thanx foe ur ans but what are the steps of refactring

Comment: Simply remove everything thats not needed for displaying or user interaction. Outsource data connections/request, start new activities instead of changing the views and so on...

Comment: Paste the relevant lines from logcat here.  There should be some complaints from the verifier ("VFY").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used about 500 lines of switch case with atleast 25 case in it ,i put all the cases in if else condition and My problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I fixed it by changing the file extension of the jar file from .JAR to .jar